# hg: Commit some changes to another branch

Tags: mercurial

I was working in `branch-a` when I found an unrelated bug that should be fixed in the `default` branch. So, I'd like commit some of my changes to `default`, then merge `default` into the current branch, and keep working.

As far as I know, Mercurial doesn't allow committing directly into another branch, so I would have to switch to the default branch first. The problem is, I can't simply checkout the default branch, because the other changes would cause conflicts. One workflow I can think of is to shelve, checkout default, unshelve only the files that relate to the fix, commit, checkout branch-a, merge default, and finally, unshelve the rest of the files. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Commit only subset of files, related to `branch-a` changes (use additionally power of Record Extension, if bugfix's and branch-a's  changes happens in some file(s) - commit only needed hunks of file) as changeset A

If you haven't MQ Extension:

- Commit the rest of changes into `branch-a` as changeset B (child of A)
- Rebase B (with Rebase Extension) changeset into `default` branch with `--keep` option in oder to have B in original location also

If you have MQ extension

- Create new patch with working-dir changes
- Unapply MQ-patch
- Update to `default`
- Apply patch
- Test, test...
- Finish patch (convert to permanent changeset)
- Graft *this changeset only* into `branch-a` branch

Comment: Thanks! I was only vaguely aware of rebase, but now I see the point of it.

Comment: It's good to know the rebase and mq-patch ways of doing this. However the shelve -> switch branch -> unshelve seems to be easier for me. Thanks anyway.